# How in java i can execute postgres function and procedure with jpa?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a function in postgres how can I run it, I tried it via

```
@Procedure (procedureName = "function_name")
    void insertData ();
```

but i get exceptions

Comment: What exceptions?

Comment: @FrankHeikens more my question is, where should I place such a function as I attached in the question above, because if I place in the repository, I need to inherit from jparepositoty or crud and in generycs write type and id of my objet, but my function is not connected with no object, it just creates tables in the database